# Как отобразить окно как диалог?

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, prism

У меня есть подготовленное окно для показа диалога, но как дошло дело до его показа, я не понимаю как отобразить это окно как диалог.

В `Prism` есть сервис `IDialogService`, но я не понимаю как им воспользоваться, т.к. при попытке отобразить окно, мне выдает исключение:

> Exception occurred while:
>
> on constructor:  DialogWindow()  •resolving type:  'IDialogWindow'
>   mapped to 'DialogWindow' "
>
> InvalidOperationException: Вызывающим потоком должен быть STA,
>   поскольку этого требуют большинство компонентов UI.

Такое исключение бросается если использовать асинхронную команду, а если использовать синхронную то:

> "A dialog's content must be a FrameworkElement"

Как я пытаюсь показать диалог:

```
public class ShortUserProfileViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private readonly IDialogService _dialogService;
    private DelegateCommand _loginCommand;

    public ShortUserProfileViewModel(IDleHttpClient httpClient, IDialogService dialogService)
    {
        _dialogService = dialogService;
        HttpClient = httpClient;
        LoginCommand = new DelegateCommand(() =>
        {
            _dialogService.ShowDialog("UserAuthWindow", new DialogParameters(), result =>
            {

            });
        });
    }

    public IDleHttpClient HttpClient { get; }

    public DelegateCommand LoginCommand
    {
        get => _loginCommand;
        set => SetProperty(ref _loginCommand, value);
    }
}
```

Как отобразить окно как диалог с помощью `Prism`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вот это `InvalidOperationException: Вызывающим потоком должен быть STA, поскольку этого требуют большинство компонентов UI.` означает, что вы пытаетесь показать окно не из UI потока

Comment: тут гугл говорит, что надо регистрировать свои представления  для диалога ([раз](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/1666), [два](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/pull/1682))

Comment: @tym32167, оформите ответом? [Все работает как часы!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZ0Hx.png)

Comment: Дак а что мне в ответ писать? Просто сылку? Наверное будет лучше, если вы ответ в вашим кодом добавите, кодом, который работает.